# Explain pitch, width, height, depth in memory for 3D arrays

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I am working with CUDA and 3D textures in python (using pycuda). There is a function called [Memcpy3D](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pycuda.driver.Memcpy3D) which has the same members as [Memcpy2D](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pycuda.driver.Memcpy2D) plus a few extras. In it it calls you to describe things such as `width_in_bytes`, `src_pitch`, `src_height`, `height` and `copy_depth`. This is what I am struggling with (in 3D) and its relevance with C or F style indexing. For instance, if I simply change the ordering from F to C in the working example below, it stops working - and I don't know why.

1. First of all, I understand pitch to be how many bytes in memory it takes to move one index across in `threadIdx.x` (or the x direction, or a column). So for a float32 array of C shape (3,2,4), to move one value in x I expect to move 4 values in memory ([as the indexing goes down the z axis first?](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/images/2015/row-major-3D.png)). Therefore my pitch would be 4*32bits.
2. I understand `height` to be the number of rows. (In this example, 3)
3. I understand `width` to be the number of cols. (In this example, 2)
4. I understand `depth` to be the number of z slices. (In this example, 4)
5. I understand `width_in_bytes` to be the width of a row in x **inclusive** of the z elements behind it, i.e. a row slice, (0,:,:). This would be how many addresses in memory it takes to transverse one element in the y-direction.

So when I change the ordering from F to C in the code below, and adapt the code to change the height/width values accordingly it still doesn't work. It just presents a logic failure which makes me think I'm not understanding the concept of pitch, width, height, depth correctly.

Please educate me.

Below is a full working script that copies an array to the GPU as a texture and copies the contents back.

```
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np

w = 2
h = 3
d = 4
shape = (w, h, d)

a = np.arange(24).reshape(*shape,order='F').astype('float32')
print(a.shape,a.strides)
print(a)


descr = drv.ArrayDescriptor3D()
descr.width = w
descr.height = h
descr.depth = d
descr.format = drv.dtype_to_array_format(a.dtype)
descr.num_channels = 1
descr.flags = 0

ary = drv.Array(descr)

copy = drv.Memcpy3D()
copy.set_src_host(a)
copy.set_dst_array(ary)
copy.width_in_bytes = copy.src_pitch = a.strides[1]
copy.src_height = copy.height = h
copy.depth = d

copy()

mod = SourceModule("""
    texture<float, 3, cudaReadModeElementType> mtx_tex;

    __global__ void copy_texture(float *dest)
    {
      int x = threadIdx.x;
      int y = threadIdx.y;
      int z = threadIdx.z;
      int dx = blockDim.x;
      int dy = blockDim.y;
      int i = (z*dy + y)*dx + x;
      dest[i] = tex3D(mtx_tex, x, y, z);
    }
""")

copy_texture = mod.get_function("copy_texture")
mtx_tex = mod.get_texref("mtx_tex")

mtx_tex.set_array(ary)

dest = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.float32, order="F")
copy_texture(drv.Out(dest), block=shape, texrefs=[mtx_tex])

print(dest)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the problem in your code, but I'll attempt to clarify.

In CUDA, `width` (`x`) refers to the fastest-changing dimension, `height` (`y`) is the middle dimension, and `depth` (`z`) is the slowest-changing dimension. The `pitch` refers to the stride in bytes required to step between values along the `y` dimension.

In Numpy, an array defined as `np.empty(shape=(3,2,4), dtype=np.float32, order="C")` has `strides=(32, 16, 4)`, and corresponds to `width=4`, `height=2`, `depth=3`, `pitch=16`.

Using `"F"` ordering in Numpy means the order of dimensions is reversed in memory.

Your code appears to work if I make the following changes:

```
#shape = (w, h, d)
shape = (d, h, w)

#a = np.arange(24).reshape(*shape,order='F').astype('float32')
a = np.arange(24).reshape(*shape,order='C').astype('float32')
...
#dest = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.float32, order="F")
dest = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.float32, order="C")
#copy_texture(drv.Out(dest), block=shape, texrefs=[mtx_tex])
copy_texture(drv.Out(dest), block=(w,h,d), texrefs=[mtx_tex])
```